# Pushing a Lua table

Tags: c++, c, lua, stack, lua-table

I have created a Lua table in **C**, but I'm not sure how to push that table onto the top of a stack so I can pass it to a Lua function.

Does anyone know how to do this?

This is my current code:

```
lua_createtable(state, libraries.size(), 0);
int table_index = lua_gettop(state);
for (int i = 0; i < libraries.size(); i++)
{
    lua_pushstring(state, libraries[i].c_str());
    lua_rawseti(state, table_index, i + 1);
}

lua_settable(state, -3);

[ Push other things ]
[ Call function ]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a quick helper function to push strings to the table

```
void l_pushtablestring(lua_State* L , char* key , char* value) {
    lua_pushstring(L, key);
    lua_pushstring(L, value);
    lua_settable(L, -3);
}
```

Here I use the helper function to create the table and pass it to a function

```
// create a lua function
luaL_loadstring(L, "function fullName(t) print(t.fname,t.lname) end");
lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);

// push the function to the stack
lua_getglobal(L, "fullName");

// create a table in c (it will be at the top of the stack)
lua_newtable(L);
l_pushtablestring(L, "fname", "john");
l_pushtablestring(L, "lname", "stewart");

// call the function with one argument
lua_pcall(L, 1, 0, 0);
```

Comment: How would I push two different tables to the same function?

Comment: The second argument in lua_pcall is the number of arguments being passed to the function so you would push both tables onto the stack and then change the pcall to lua_pcall(L, 2, 0, 0);

Answer (score 2):

The table is already in the stack, where `lua_newtable` left it, isn't it?

Comment: If it is, I must be making the table incorrectly. Could you tell me how I should be creating the table? All it needs to contain is some strings.

Comment: See http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lua.c.html#getargs for instance. Or show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

I made a small snippet open source that solves pushing simple Lua dictionary tables from C to Lua.

You can check it out [here](https://github.com/Goles/Nano-Lua-Dictionary), should work well.